# Is a question mark in a TAF forecast ever valid?

Tags: taf

One will sometimes see a question mark in the body of a TAF (Terminal Aerodrome Forecast), such as in the second line below:

```
TAF MDLR 162200Z 1700/1800 00000KT 9999 SCT018
  PROB30 1704/1710 8000 ?SHRA BKN016 
  BECMG 1713/1715 07010KT
```

Is there any time that this is correct, or should it always be considered a typo when it is encountered?  I haven't found any references to such an annotation while searching online, but those resources tend to be FAA-centric, and if other weather reporting uses that punctuation to convey a specific meaning, I'd be interested to know about that.

Comment: I entered the TAF in your question into a TAF decoder program and the result shown for "?SHRA" was "*not decoded*. "  I'm guessing it would be a typo. See: https://e6bx.com/taf-decoder/

Comment: @757toga Good thought on that.  The decoder at aviationWeather.gov seems to ignore the question mark & decodes it as if it were just "SHRA" rather than "?SHRA". I'm hoping to see if any jurisdiction besides FAA-land uses that punctuation to coney information -- I'm pretty certain that in the US, it'd just be a typo if it shows up.  I realize that I may be asking for somebody to "prove a negative" here, which may be tough.  A lack of any "yes" may be all the answer I can hope for.

Comment: In METARs, a question mark indicates that the reading is not reliable.  Presumably the equipment is throwing error codes and needs maintenance.  Maybe this pertains to TAFs as well?

Comment: @SkipMiller Sounds reasonable.  But do you have a reference that shows that a question mark in a METAR means a *reading is not reliable.*?

Comment: A TAF isn't a *reading*, but rather a *forecast*; the lack of a rain/visibility/whatever sensor removes that value from a METAR report, but a forecast should still be able to predict all those thing, I'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no question marks nor any reference to them in neither the ICAO Annex 3 nor the WMO 306 Manual on Codes. These documents are the standards used for meteorological reports and forecasts in aviation. There might be national exceptions to these though.

Comment: Where might one find national exceptions? Specifically, for the Dominican Republic & the Bahamas -- those seem to be where the question marks (the D.R.) and other nonstandard punctuation (slashes in Bahamian METAR reports) often show up.

Comment: I don't know, but my bests guess is the (national) Aeronautical information publication (AIP). Maybe you could ask the local weather briefing if such is available